# Multiple USB wireless devices?

Tags: usb, wifi, broadcom

I have a broadcom wireless card in my laptop and as far as I know, it acts as an USB device.
I also have one USB stick wireless device (TL-WN422G - uses ath9k_htc driver) which I want to use at the same time as the first (Broadcom) device.

The problem is, after I load ath9k_htc - iwconfig does not show the new USB device (the TL-WN422G - wlan1 / ath0 / whatever), but only the old one (wlan0 - Broadcom, checked by MAC).

I tried this USB device (TL-WN422G) on my other computer that has PCI wireless card in it, and they both worked just fine together after I pluged it in... I get wlan0 (Ralink) and wlan1 (TL-WN422G).
Is it some kind of a problem for the laptop that both devices are recognized as USB?
How do I make wlan1 appear on my laptop?

also, my system is fully up to date 2.6.35 kernel (Arch)

**edit:** 
I've already downloaded the needed ar9271.fw from linuxwireless.org and I put it into /lib/firmware - something wrong in that?

dmesg gives me this on laptop:

```
usb 1-5: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 9
usb 1-5: ath9k_htc: Firmware - ar9271.fw not found
ath9k_hif_usb: probe of 1-5:1.0 failed with error -22
```

and this on the computer that does work:

```
usb 1-5: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
usb 1-5: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ar9271.fw, size: 51280
ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x809c
ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x52
ath: Country alpha2 being used: CN
ath: Regpair used: 0x52
cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: CN
Registered led device: ath9k-phy1::radio
Registered led device: ath9k-phy1::assoc
Registered led device: ath9k-phy1::tx
Registered led device: ath9k-phy1::rx
usb 1-5: ath9k_htc: USB layer initialized
usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_hif_usb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for some reason the `ar9721.fw` file was empty… downloaded the file again – put it into /lib/firmware and now it works…